# VNC: pressing Shift + Tab = Tab only

Tags: keyboard, vnc, vino

I'm using VNC to access an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop (running Desktop Sharing) from a Windows 10 desktop (running Ultra VNC Viewer). My problem: some keyboard combos don't travel well; for example, pressing `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Tab` is processed on the server as `Ctrl`+`Tab`.

The problem persists when using a different VNC client, for example MobaXTerm, so the issue seems to be on the Ubuntu side. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Does the shift key work on the windows 10 system? Does using either right or left shift change it?

Comment: Both Shift keys work on the Win10 desktop, but in both cases, sending `Shift`+`Tab` gets interpreted as `Tab`. Other combos, like `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`F` work (Search Backwards, in Terminal), so the problem may be limited to `Shift`+`Tab`. (`Shift`+`Tab`works correctly from the Linux laptop's physical keyboard.)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @UTAN_dev Ubuntu physical laptop keyboard - Ubuntu remote desktop - same problem, so that is not true.

Answer (score 11):

Instruction from this (2009) thread solved the issue for me: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353304#c21

Solution:
Run in Ubuntu terminal: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Tab'`

EDIT: to make the fix permanent (for 18.04) run `sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and change the line

> `key  <TAB> {  [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };`

to

> `key  <TAB> {  [ Tab                   ]   };`

After that reboot.

Comment: You run the command on *remote*, just to be clear, tested, works on remote Ubuntu 20.04