# Shift + special key does not work using real vnc viewer in windows to access ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, remote-desktop, vnc, vino

Same issue as this: [VNC: pressing Shift + Tab = Tab only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839842/vnc-pressing-shift-tab-tab-only/1084855)

I can write "A" by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, but <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> won't work. Tab be triggered without the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. This has been an issue since at least 16 I think when I started using the gnome variant of Ubuntu. Right now I am using PopOS 18.04 and with both tigerVNC and Real VNC Viewer (on Windows 10) I have the same issue connecting to the Vino VNC server. Without the VNC connection <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> works as expected on both Linux and Windows.

I also tried with tiger VNC viewer on the Linux subsystem. Same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending two days with this issue I have found this thread from 2009: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=353304#c21

Solution:
Run in Ubuntu terminal: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 23 = Tab'`

EDIT: to make the fix permanent run `sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and change the line

> `key  <TAB> {  [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };`

to

> `key  <TAB> {  [ Tab                   ]   };`

After that reboot.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly for me. Since you have done the research, would you care to add some reasons behind to this answer to help us understand this issue? Thank you.